# Combining swap and pair function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am very new to haskell and i have begun reading the book 'programming in haskell'. I came across the function called swap

```
swap (x,y) = (y,x)
```

and the function pair.

```
pair x y = (x,y)
```

Then i began to wonder if it was possible to combine these two functions somehow like this

```
swapPair x y = (y,x)
```

and using the two priar functions as help functions.

Comment: The answers below provide several alternatives, including some in the so-called "pointfree style". Yet, if you are a beginner, I'd suggest you focus only on the simplest, direct composition `swapPair x y = swap (pair x y)` and ignore the more advanced options, which do not actually improve readability nor performance.

Comment: There's a basic Haskell higher-order function called `curry` with type `((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c`. It takes a [function which consumes a tuple and returns something] and returns a [function that consumes the first element of the tuple and returns a [function that consumes the second element of the tuple and returns something]]. `swapPair` is `curry swap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious way this can be done is

```
swapPair x y = swap (pair x y)
```

which is the same as

```
swapPair x y = swap $ pair x y
```

Because `y` appears only at the end of both sides, it can be *eta-reduced*. That requires changing the application operator to a composition one:

```
swapPair x = swap . pair x
```

As Willem Van Onsem showed, this can be made completely point-free. I would not recommend that, but here's how it works: you first consider that the `.` operator is itself a function that's being applied to some arguments

```
swapPair x = (.) swap (pair x)
```

Then this can be written as a composition again:

```
swapPair x = (.) swap . pair $ x
```

eta-reduce

```
swapPair = (.) swap . pair
```

and finally *operator section* syntax can be applied:

```
swapPair = (swap .) . pair
```

Comment: Just to give it a name, athough it is not commonly used it has been floating around for a long time `(.:) = (.) . (.)`  it can be defined as `swap .: pair`. I recently discovered [Agda has the ability to define it `swap ◦ ◦ pair`](https://gist.github.com/Icelandjack/2eb99db6a1ab904b709571f1e9cd36b4) using mixfix operators. This doesn't require defining more and more operators.

Answer (score 3):

You can use these with:

```
swapPair :: a -> b -> (b, a)
swapPair = (swap .) . pair
```

Here we thus pass the two parameters first to `pair` to create a 2-tuple, and then we apply `swap` on that 2-tuple.

But we can do this without `swap` and `pair`, and just work with:

```
swapPair :: a -> b -> (b, a)
swapPair = flip (,)
```